# Can RStudio be configured to run app in a Shiny project by default?

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio, run-app

Can RStudio be configured to launch my project as a Shiny app even when the `server.R`, `ui.R` or `app.R` files are *not* in focus?

I know I can use the `runApp` function in the console, but would like to just hit the menu button or, even better, a keyboard shortcut, to launch my Shiny app regardless of the last script file I just edited.